# C#: How to add a class member named "protected"

Tags: c#, api, json.net

I'm fairly new to C# but have extensive experience in Objective-C and OOP. I'm using Json.NET to automatically parse API responses to objects. It so happens that one of the objects returned has a property named **protected**. Obviously this is a problem, because protected is a keyword for class member declaration.

```
"protected": true
```

1. Is it possible to add a member with the name *protected* at all?
2. Is it possible to add setters and getters that get triggered, if the parser tries to set the protected property? (but assign the value to a private member named _protected)
3. Should I modify the parser to behave different when he encounters a property named *protected*?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1:

For question #1: You can put an @ symbol before it any keyword you want to use as a variable name.

E.g.

`public string @protected {get; set; }`

I recommend **against** doing this, however. You should be able to remap the "protected" field in your JSON to a different property in your POCO.

## 2:

```
private string _protected;

public string @protected 
{
    get 
    {
       //any additional code you want
        return _protected;
    }
    set
    {
       //any additional code you want
        _protected = value;
    }
}
```

## 3:

Up to you!

Comment: Recommend against it why? I can't change the API to return different named fields and if it is "just adding an @", why not do it?

Comment: Because any developer that inherits your code is instantly confused, I'f its got to be done I'd give a second property accessor to "_protected" and use a `[System.Obsolete]` tag on this one to stop it being used

Comment: You should be able to rename it by using the `JsonProperty` attribute. E.g. `[JsonProperty("protected")] public string SomethingOtherThanProtected {get; set;}`

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this solution:

```
[JsonProperty("protected")] public bool Protected { get; set; }
```

Like Daniel Mann suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303235/c-how-to-add-a-class-member-named-protected/18303245?noredirect=1#comment26856581_18303245):

Comment: Site etiquette would be to accept my answer and not post your own answer saying that you used my answer :)